# Is it possible to use packer to create an image in a private subnet via a bastion?

Tags: packer, winrm

I am trying to use packer to create a Windows image. I'd like to create the instance on a private subnet i.e. inaccessible to the public internet.

Is it possible to do this via a bastion (or by some other means)?

I see from the docs that I can use a bastion for SSH communication: https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html#ssh_bastion_host

...and I can also use WinRM for communication: https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html#winrm_host

I've tried combining the two sets of options but it just sits at "Waiting for WinRM to become available..." which suggests that isn't supported.

What are my options for using packer to create an instance in a private subnet?

Comment: Probably not helpful but have you checked security group permissions between the bastion and the packer instance being spawned? I'm not sure if packer handles that itself or not.

Comment: Packer does seem to handle that: the newly-spawned instance has an allow rule for 5985.

Comment: Oops, accidentally posted too soon. What about on the bastion instance? Does it have a) outgoing access for 5985 on the private subnet CIDR? b) incoming ssh from your IP?

Comment: Outgoing is basically allow-all (default for an AWS instance), and incoming allows SSH (as I can SSH tunnel through the bastion manually).

Comment: can the bastion box be linux server?

Comment: @stusmith did you ever end up solving this?  I'm in a similar situation where  Packer doesn't seem to try and connect to the Bastion host

Comment: @djt - No, I didn't solve this directly. We took an alternate approach in the end - we now have a packer "service": a little NodeJS app running on an instance in a private subnet, that manages the running of packer via a HTTP interface. We can then tunnel to that service instead of trying to get packer itself to do the tunnelling.